# i want to create a circlize circos plot with R or Python

Tags: python, r, circos

I have a CSV file with two columns: one for the names of proteins and another for the concentrations of these proteins. Some proteins share the same concentrations. I would like to create a Circos plot using R or Python to visualize the connections between proteins that share the same concentration.

P.S.: I have attempted several codes, but I keep encountering errors.

Comment: please post the code that you've tried and an example of your data. however: why would you do this? I would be surprised if any biological system had proteins of the exact same measure concentrations. why a circos rather than e.g. a network?

Comment: try this:   https://pypi.org/project/pyCirclize

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in my comment, I think you are overcomplicating this.

If you need this visualization as stated and your data are as you say, try a network instead:

```
library(igraph)

# substitute your data
example = data.frame(cbind(
  c("P53", "cycB", "AuroraB", "CDK1", "MCM8"),
  c(1, 1, 3, 2, 2))
)
g = graph_from_data_frame(example)
plot(g)
```

this makes a plot, which is somewhat ugly but can be readily prettied up using igraph plotting stuff:

[image]

You can do something very similar in python. I haven't run this, but it should more or less work:

```
import igraph
import pandas as pd

example = pd.DataFrame(
  [["P53", "cycB", "AuroraB", "CDK1", "MCM8"],
  [1, 1, 3, 2, 2]]
)
g = igraph.Graph.DataFrame(edges, directed=False)
igraph.plot(g)
```